# How I can remove extension from string in list (groovy)?

Tags: groovy

I have list `def list = ['values.txt']` and I want to remove extension from filename and receive string . How I can do this ?

Expecting result is -- `filename = 'values'`.

Comment: Is the list always only going to contain one value?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to open ANY Groovy book or tutorial you would find a lot of solutions.

For example:

```
def list = ['values.txt']
def noExtensions = list.collect{ it.split( /\./ )[ 0 ] }
assert ['values'] == noExtensions
```

Comment: Consider marking these answer as Resolving to help others :)